# How to activate the legacyDecorators option in babel?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, decorator

I want to use a Decorater for my component. However i encounter the following error message:

```
Parsing error: Using the export keyword between a decorator and a class is not allowed. Please use `export @dec class` instead.
```

I found the solution in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54516632/12818045) recommending to use the `legacyDecorators` option in the `.eslintrc` file.

```
{    
  "parserOptions": {
     "ecmaFeatures": {
       "legacyDecorators": true
     }
   }
}
```

However, i have no idea where i have to insert that code to activate the legacy option.

**Update**

I meanwhile ejected my create-react-app and im now able to configure babel and eslint (eslintConfig) directly in package.jason as you see below.

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.28",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "3.4.2",
    "d3-ease": "^1.0.6",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "4.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.10.3",
    "html-to-react": "^1.4.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.11",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-kit-react": "^1.8.0",
    "mdbreact": "^4.25.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "pure-react-carousel": "^1.26.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-alert": "^6.0.1",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.11.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "react-bootstrap-carousel": "^4.0.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-geocode": "^0.2.1",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "^1.1.2",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-h5-audio-player": "^2.4.2",
    "react-image-appear": "^1.2.23",
    "react-loading-image": "^0.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.9",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.15.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "2.3.4",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "url-loader": "2.3.0",
    "webpack": "4.41.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.10.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
     "ecmaFeatures": {
       "legacyDecorators": true
     }
   }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {
          "legacy": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.10.1"
  }
}
```

I added the proposed lines under babel. However the same issue still appears.

Comment: please post your .babelrc (or equivalent) config

Answer (score 1):

You posted a code to configure, a static code linter called "eslint". But i dont think your error is related.

I think your error is related to transpiling your code.

So in case you are using babel to transpile your code.

This is what you need to add in your [.babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files) file for it to work, and of course install the needed dependency [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators)

```
    "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      } 
    ],   
],
```

in any case, the code you posted need to go into [.eslintrc](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) file, **but its important only if are using eslint**. And even if eslint throws an this error you can disable it by just adding

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

on the top of your code or just disabling it as a whole.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question, is it necassary to eject my Create React App in order to activate the the legacy option?

Comment: I'm not using RCA. (not yet anyway) But i don't think its relevant. First: you can provide babel settings inside package.json (heres how https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#packagejson) and second its possible that once you have .babelrc present in your project RCA will merge its content into its own config (but im not sure ATM)