# ESLint Error using Vue Class Component, Vuex-class

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'd like to use `vuex-class` for binding helpers for [vuex](/questions/tagged/vuex) and `vue-class-component`

But it says

`` error  Parsing error: Using the export keyword between a decorator and a class is not allowed. Please use `export @dec class` instead. ``

**App.vue**

```js
@Component
export default  class App extends Vue {
  mounted() {
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54516632/6277151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put the export at the end :

```
@Component
 class App extends Vue {
  mounted() {
  ...
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Is there any solution to use `export default`?

Comment: as i suggested or you could try out `export default @component  class App extends Vue {...`